# show output folder after process

Tags: c#, winforms

***I have 2 forms in windows form apps.In the first one i have browse button and 1 textbox that keep the address by this code:

---

```
 private void Browsbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox2.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;

        }
    }
```

now in the 2nd form i have showOutput button...so when i click on this button i want that, it shows the folder that user saved by browse button on the first form .how is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

To make things clean you could add a settings to your application:

- open Visual Studio menu *Project -> Project Name properties*

[image]

- go to *Settings* tab and add a string setting such as LastFolderSelected

[image]

Save your selected folder in first form :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog())
        {
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.LastFolderSelected = dialog.SelectedPath;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Retrieve your folder in second form like this :

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string lastFolderSelected = Properties.Settings.Default.LastFolderSelected;
    }
}
```

I think this is the preferred method against referencing form 2 in form 1 or whatever.

Comment: thanks for your reply.but i want a solution on click event of show output button...

Comment: You can put that code anywhere you need it, if you want more help put your code where your problem is.

Comment: ok.please answer this question:How can i have access to the controls of form one from form 2?for example if i save the path in the textbox of form one how can i open that path by clicking on button in form 2?